# What coordinate frame does rviz set the 2D Nav Goal in?

Tags: navigation, rviz, turtlebot2, turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've got a Turtlebot 2 in ROS Groovy, and I've been learning about navigation. One thing that confuses me is what happens internally in rviz when I press the "2D Nav Goal" button after running `roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch` as done in the tutorial at:
http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map

I know that it sends a goal to the navfn component in the move_base node (I think), but my question is, what reference is it using when I click the screen? IE, if I click on an X,Y point on the screen, what is it passing to move_base? Am I telling the robot to move some distance relative to its base_link? Or am I sending it to a fixed point on its local or global costmap?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68998/what-coordinate-frame-does-rviz-set-the-2d-nav-goal-in?/) by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on ROS Answers with karma: 504 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

In RVIZ you can choose the "fixed frame", it's always the first item in the display list.  The goal, initial pose or any other message will be send in the frame that you have selected there. By default it is /map.

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2013-07-26**:
So if I understand correctly, what gets sent to move_base is an X,Y destination relative to the global costmap?

**Comment by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on 2013-08-08**:
Well it is actually an full 3D pose (position and orientation) with respect to the /map reference frame.